# The data from Pinia store is not reactive in Nuxt 3 when switching language

Tags: vue.js, strapi, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm just starting with Nuxt and the answer could be obvious, but I'm hoping to get support from you.

I've got a 2 language website, built with Nuxt 3 that uses **Nuxt I18n** for internationalization, which retrieves data from an API (a strapi headless cms). I've managed to set up a Pinia store in order to not overuse the API, which looks like this:

```
// /stores/store.js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useFetch } from "#app";

export const useStore = defineStore("store", {
    state: () => ({
        data: {
            en: [],
            ru: []
        }
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchData() {
            let resEn = await useFetch('strapi-url.com/api/data', {
                params: {
                    locale: 'en'
                }
            });

            if (resEn.error.value) {
                throw createError({
                    statusCode: resEn.error.value.statusCode,
                    statusMessage: resEn.error.value.statusMessage
                });
            }

            this.data.en = resEn.data;

            let resFr = await useFetch('strapi-url.com/api/data', {
                params: {
                    locale: 'fr'
                }
            });

            if (resFr.error.value) {
                throw createError({
                    statusCode: resFr.error.value.statusCode,
                    statusMessage: resFr.error.value.statusMessage
                });
            }

            this.data.fr = resFr.data;
        }
    }
});
```

And to make the data available when app loads I've setup the `app.vue` file:

```
<script setup>
import { useStore } from "~/stores/store";

const store = usetStore();
await store.fetchData();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <Header/>
    <NuxtPage/>
    <Footer/>
  </div>
</template>
```

and then in a component (example: `Header.vue`) I'm getting the data from the store an render it:

```
<script setup>
import { useStore } from "~/stores/NewsletterStore";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

const { locale } = useI18n();

const store = useStore();
const { data } = storeToRefs(store);

const title = data[locale].title;
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ title }}
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is that when the language changes, by a locale switcher, the data isn't refreshed, even if the `locale` changes too.

I would like to know if there's any way to make it reactive, based on the selected locale.

Looking forward.

I've tried to setup a pinia store using nuxt 3 web app that has 2 languages controlled by Nuxt I18n module that consumes data from an strapi backend API, but the data rendered isn't reactive when changing locale. I expect to know how to make this data be reactive, when language changes?

Comment: `data[locale].title` - things like this should always go to a computed, unless you want to disable the reactivity. `locale` is supposed to be a ref if it's reactive (it is), it's incorrect to use it not as `locale.value` here. Not specific to Nuxt

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your comment, but this ``const data = computed(() => data.value[locale.value]); `` doesn't even contain the data.

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve], using codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem. It looks like the layout isn't updating store data.
A way around it is to bind a key on the header to force a remount on locale change eg.

```
:key="`header-${locale}`"
```

I'm not particularly thrilled with this solution, so if anyone has been able to look into this further, let me know.